# I have screwed up a question

Tags: discussion

I've recently asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510616/when-is-begin-required-in-awk) for which I have two good answers. I've up-voted both answers, but not yet designated one as the "correct" answer.

Since the answers have been posted, I've realized I made a mistake in my question: I incorrectly asserted that two similar commands gave the same output, when in fact they do not. I don't know how I managed to screw that up, but I did.

I've read an [answer with advice on a similar situation](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2657/286615), but it's a bit different situation.

My question is what to do about my screwed-up question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [slm's answer there](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2657/117549) applies here, too.

The core question you've asked -- in both the title and in the only question in your question -- is about the `BEGIN` statement in `awk`, which is what at least one answer has addressed. I would leave this question alone, apart from accepting any answer that you find useful.

Questions are free, so if you have a separate concern about the two commands, ask that separately.

I don't see a major impediment to your question by leaving the misunderstanding; I might even go so far as to edit the Q (or leave a comment on it) indicating that your original assumption was incorrect, in order to focus any future answers on your core question.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach, and that's what I'll do. As an aside, I suppose now I should ask a question along the lines of. "What set of circumstances will cause these two statements to yield the same answer?" Then I'd learn where I screwed up :)